# Stop scroll when loading screen is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website that has a loading screen while the page loads in the background. What I am trying to do, is stop body scroll when the loading screen is visible. I have had a ton of bad luck with it. I have tried over 15 different options and nothing seems to work. My jQuery code goes as follows.

```
$(".loading-screen").delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
 if($('.loading-screen').is(':hidden'))
 {
 $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
 }
```

I have disabled the overflow on the body in my css and am attempting to make the overflow visible once the loading screen fades out.

This is an image of the loading screen.
[screenshot of loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXb6J.png)

I have attempted many different solutions and nothing is working... curious about your guys possible solutions to this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to hide your body content till loading is completed?

Comment: Also, you did not give us a whole lot of code to work with here. Not sure what your html structure looks like.

Comment: Here is the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2ff0d25b27c93fd2c09d69bd6481dd38

Comment: `.fadeOut(400 , function(){ //body overflow visible })`

Comment: I would set set `.main` to `display: none;` then switch to `display: block` once you hide `.loading-screen`

Comment: That didn't work sadly.

Comment: Mohamed your solution worked, thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution to my problem!

Comment: @MXM97  glad it helped .. I posted it as an answer .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) callback function like so

```
$(".loading-screen").delay(5000).fadeOut(400 , function(){
  $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
});
```

**REF**: From [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) documentation

`.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

**duration** (default: 400)
Type: Number or String
A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

**complete**
Type: Function()
A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much Appreciated!